# Spring Social 500 exception

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, jackson, spring-social

I am using Spring Social to integrate my app with Facebook. I checked out their quickstart project from github. I changed the properties file to have my own app's id.

After running the project I see the login page. But after that I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/CollectionType

description The server encountered an internal error (Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/CollectionType) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/CollectionType
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Thanks.

Edit:

As per comments,

I have to mention that I have already added Jackson jars. Have tried both versions 1.9.9 and 1.8.5.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
 </plugin>
```

I just wrote mapper for now, as it itself calls core as well. But I have also tried same thing with core. Still getting that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please download jackson jar from

[here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload)

Comment: Thank you, but I have already included those jars. I have tried versions, 1.9.9 and 1.8.5. None of them worked.

Comment: Jackson comes with Maven "pom"-files (and is available via Codehaus Maven2 repo, which gets synced with main Maven2 repository).

The only dependencies are:

Core and mapper require JDK 5
Mapper jar depends on core jar
Jax-rs, Jackson-xc and jackson-mrbean jars depend on mapper jar

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. So it seems that Social Spring works with Jackson 1.8.5 version. And also I needed to add both core and mapper jars.

Thanks everyone.